# JAR file—nothings happens when I run it

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to run a JAR file and nothing happens? Any idea why? Did I maybe do the export wrongly?

Some guidelines would be very welcome!

**update**

I sorted it!! Thanks for yr brainstorming anyway! I wasn't adding the file with the visual-material (gif-files). I think I added in the code a try-catch that check if there is any available map if there's not it'll shut down.

Comment: Can you give more informations ? What did you do ? What is the exact result ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's something that doesn't work. You will need to investigate why.

Comment: Try to run it from the command line, and see if you get any errors (java -jar thefile.jar)

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Comment: Copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

Jar files can only be executed if they contain a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF that specifies the main class (entry point) into your application. Otherwise you have to specify the class manually on the command line.

e.g. it contains

```
Main-Class: com.mycompany.App
```

Then you can just say:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

Normally you would create a manifest.txt containing this line and package it in your jar like so:

```
jar cfm MyApp.jar Manifest.txt com/mycompany/*.class
```

Java 6 also implements a parameter on the jar tool which will create/modify the entry point in an existing jar's MANIFEST.MF if you prefer.

```
jar cfe MyApp.jar com.mycompany.App com/mycompany/App.class
```

Comment: @YoniGeek: You can also specify the application entry point: http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-export-jar.htm

Comment: I'll try to answer all yr sub questions:

Comment: Just create a file anywhere called manifest.txt (the name is not important) with the Main-Class line and then when you invoke that first jar command tell it where the file is, e.g. "jar cfm c:\myworkspace\manifest.txt *.class". Alternatively you can run the second version and the jar tool will create a manifest for you inside the .jar. As trashgod says you could also use tools in Eclipse or Netbeans to do this too. Eclipse has an export wizard for the job. If you were using Maven, you could specify the main class with the maven-jar-plugin and mainClass tag.

Comment: hi Locka! Well Im actually using Eclipse , so I suppose that Eclipse provides a manifest file right?

Comment: I sorted it anyway!! I wasn't adding  the file with the visual-material (gif-files). I think I added in the code a try-catch that check if there is any available map if there's not it would shut down....thanks anyway! yr nickname is very Scandinavian btw ^_^)